# What is lastest version of Android studio that fully support windows 7 64 bit

Tags: android-studio

I got a big problem with programs and I totally hate the dev. and everyone they know, why they don't make or tell us what the version of them still can use on windows 7 what happen on they brain.

version of android studio that support on windows 7

Comment: Considering the last release of Windows 7 came out 6 years before the first release of Android Studio, I suspect that _no_ version of Android Studio supports Windows 7.